# Problem with NavigationBar and UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, uinavigationbar

in my app delegate I've this:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"HeaderViewBG.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

for set a background image for navigationbar. But I need to use a UIImagePickerController, so I've this code:

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

I want the default UIImagePickerController navigationbar style. I don't want the image background used in application, I want the default navigationbar.

How can I fix it?

Very thanks.

Comment: well, did you? I am also intrigued to know.

Answer (score 0):

remove code for navigation bar and remove the statement where you call drawRect this function.

it remove the custom navigation bar and then you get default navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue >= 8.0) {
            [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar1"]]];
        } else {
            [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar2"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
    viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    titleLabel.text = @"photos";
    [viewController.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
    viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
}
```